# Python: Automatic sharding in FileSystems.create() for a writing channel in Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I was using [FileSystems](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/filesystems.py#L157-L170) inside a ParDo to be able to write to dynamic destinations in data storage.

However I was not able to do [automatic sharding as in Text.IO](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/textio.py#L349-L355) using wildcard for filename?

Is there a way that I can do automatic sharding in FileSystems.create?

Edited:
This is the pipeline I used to run, the part of code in question is WriteToStorage where I want to write the result to date{week}at{year}/results*.json

```
  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
      pcoll = (p | ReadFromText(known_args.input)
               | beam.ParDo(WriteDecompressedFile())
               | beam.Map(lambda x: ('{week}at{year}'.format(week=x['week'], year=x['year']), x))
               | beam.GroupByKey()
               | beam.ParDo(WriteToStorage()))
```

Here's the current version of WriteToStorage()

```
class WriteToStorage(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self):
      self.writer = None

  def process(self, element):
      (key, val) = element
      week, year = [int(x) for x in key.split('at')]
      if self.writer == None:
         path = known_args.output + 'date-{week}at{year}/revisions-from-{rev}.json'.format(week=week, year=year, rev=element['rev_id'])
         self.writer = filesystems.FileSystems.create(path)
         logging.info('USERLOG: Write to path %s.'%path)
      logging.info('TESTLOG: %s.'%type(val))
      for output in val:
          self.writer.write(json.dumps(output) + '\n')

  def finish_bundle(self):
      if not(self.writer == None):
         self.writer.close()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`StartBundle()`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.3.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html?highlight=dofn#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn.start_bundle) method of your `DoFn` to open a connection to a new file for each worker.

However, you have to figure out a way to independently name your files. `Text.IO` seems to do this with [`_RoundRobinKeyFn`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/iobase.py#L1007).

A simpler way would be to use a timestamp for name generation, but I don't know how foolproof this would be.

Comment: Thank you Robbe! However it seems like in that case I cannot use the input to ParDo for creating the file in the StartBundle() stage.

Comment: Could you share some code on how you are currently using FileSystems in your ParDo?

Comment: You are using `GroupByKey()` in front of your `WriteToStorage()`, which means that all elements with the same key will be processed by the same worker. Sharding is done per worker, so you would not gain anything from using it.